# Qsorting from a bin file, not displaying anything

Tags: c, arrays, bin, qsort

Having trouble with this. I've done a lot of reading on qsort the past day, and I THINK I have a decent grasp on it, but I am struggling with it when using it in conjuction with a file (bin or text). It makes me believe the problem may not lie in the int compare or qsorting, but the actual process of opening and closing the file, or the fread itself. It COULD be the array "Order" is the culprit. I have tried various iterations of the code listed below, with no luck.

My goal is to simply use qsort to make the arriving airports in order. I also need to convert the timestamp to be human readable which I do not understand how to do yet, but I figured I need to get my array working before I even bother.

If anyone is interested, the bin file in question has been uploaded at http://www.filedropper.com/acars_1

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>




            typedef struct MyStruct_struct{
            char FlightNum[7];
            char OriginAirportCode[5];
            char DestAirportCode[5];
            unsigned timeStamp;
        } MyStruct;


        MyStruct Order[5000];

        int compare (const void *v1, const void *v2)
        {
        int result;
        const MyStruct *ia = (MyStruct *)v1;
        const MyStruct *ib = (MyStruct *)v2;

            if ((result= strcmp(ia-> OriginAirportCode, ib-> OriginAirportCode)) != 0)
            return result;
            if ((result = strcmp(ia->DestAirportCode, ib->DestAirportCode)) != 0)
            return result;
            else return 0;

         }

        int main(){
        int i;



             FILE * bin;
             MyStruct myStruct;

             bin = fopen("acars.bin", "rb");
                               while(!feof(bin))
             {
                         fread(&myStruct,sizeof(MyStruct),1,bin);
             qsort(Order, 5000, sizeof( MyStruct), compare);


             }


            for (i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            printf("%i) %s, %s, %s\n", i, Order[i].FlightNum, Order[i].OriginAirportCode, Order[i].DestAirportCode);

            }
            fclose(bin);

            return 0;
        }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You must develop new functionality *in isolation*, as much as possible. You are trying to 1) handle this struct, comparing and rearranging instances of it, 2) read data from a file, and 3) perform quicksort. Which one fails? Can you read and write files of ints? Can you compare Mystructs? (Bad name, by the way.) Can you sort ints? Can you compare two airports? Can you read and write them? Can you sort a hard-coded list of them? *Narrow the problem down.*

Comment: http://imgur.com/JiRRiGs    I can read and presumably write just fine, as demonstrated here. It isn't the loop. It has something to do with the array I created, or the int compare.

Comment: That's a good first step. Now try reading two of those things into a `Mysctruct[2]`, and then printing them out. Or try hard-coding two of them and comparing them. (I won't try it because using filedropper seems to involve more work than I feel like doing-- you should consider posting a function that generates a small file of airports.)

Comment: Thank you, the weirdest thing is, I created a new project and placed the bin file in there. http://imgur.com/yZAFgkt as you can see, it got what I wanted it to do, sort the Destination flights in order. Something must of been incorrect in regards to reading the file.

Comment: Ok, one more thing is that you don't check `fopen` result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are sorting 5000 elements while you might have less than 5000. Also, you are reading to `myStruct` instead of `Order`

You may want to use code like this:

```
int count = 0;
while (!feof(bin)) {
    fread(Order + count, sizeof(MyStruct), 1, bin);
    ++count;
}

qsort(Order, count, sizeof(MyStruct), compare);
```

Or you can even change the while loop to consist of a single line:

```
while (!feof(bin)) fread(Order + (count++), sizeof(MyStruct), 1, bin);
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the file is written with full sized structures of `MyStruct`. What I mean is: are you sure that, say 3 symbol string `OriginAirportCode` is written with 5 symbols and not just four symbols (just one extra for '\0').

Comment: KMCO is one of the Airport codes, they are all 4 symbols with an extra 5 for the \0. See  
http://imgur.com/JiRRiGs